# Flux of $(x,y,z^2)$ through $\{(x,y,z): 2(x^2+y^2)<z<3\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Let $$D=\{(x,y,z): 2(x^2+y^2)<z<3\}$$
and the vector field $$F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z^2)$$

> I wanto to compute the flux of $F$ through $\partial D$

Applying the divergence theorem, I should compute

$$\int_D2+2z \ dxdydz$$
To evaluate the integral I pass to cylindrical coordinates but I have some problems at this point. We have $$2r^2<z<3,$$ $$0<r<\sqrt{3/2}$$ so then it becomes

$$\int_D2z \ dxdydz=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{3/2}}r \ dr\int_{2r^2}^3 \ z \ dz=2\pi(\sqrt{3/2}9/2-\int_0^{\sqrt{3/2}}2r^5 \ dr)=2\pi(\sqrt{3/2}9/2-\sqrt{3/2}^6/3)$$$$+$$$$\int_D2dz=2\pi(\int_0^{\sqrt{3/2}}6r-4r^2\ dr)$$

> But this does not look good at all. So maybe I'm doing something
> wrong?

If I try computing the flux directly I first have to compute the boundary, which I am not sure about
$$\partial D=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=\frac{z}{2}, z<3\} \cup \{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\leq \frac{3}{2}, \ z=0\}=B_1 \cup B_2$$
I can parametrize $B_1$ as $$\phi:(u,v)\mapsto (u,v,2(u^2+v^2))$$ so that $$\phi_u \land \phi_v= (-4u,-4v,1)$$ and gives, for $B_1,$ the integral
$$\int_{2u^2+2v^2<3} \langle F(\phi(u,v)),\phi_u \land \phi_v \rangle dudv= \int_{2u^2+2v^2<3}-4(u^3+v^3)+4(u^2+v^2)^2 \ dudv$$ which is very ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the divergence theorem, we have to evaluate
$$\begin{align}2\pi\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{3/2}}\int_{z=2r^2}^3(2+2z)r\,dz dr&=2\pi\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{3/2}}(15r-4r^3-4r^5) dr\\&=
\left[\frac{15r^2}{2}-r^4-\frac{2r^6}{3}\right]_{r=0}^{\sqrt{3/2}}=\frac{27\pi}{2}.
\end{align}$$
As regards the direct computation, the outward flux through $B_1$ is
$$\begin{align}\int_{2u^2+2v^2<3}4(u^2+v^2)-4(u^2+v^2)^2 \ dudv&=2\pi\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3/2}}(4r^2-4r^4)r\,dr\\
&=\left[r^4-\frac{2r^6}{3}\right]_{r=0}^{\sqrt{3/2}}=0
\end{align}$$
whereas the outward flux through $B_2$ is
$$\int_{z=3,r\leq \sqrt{3/2}}z^2 r\,dr=9\cdot \frac{3\pi}{2}=\frac{27\pi}{2}.$$
Their sum is again $\frac{27\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not sure if I chose the bounds of integration right. So my passages were right ?

Comment: Can I also ask you if you agree with what I did following the approach that does not use the divergence theorem?

Comment: Yes, just check your computations. At the end the powers of $r$ are all even and the square root disappears

Comment: for example the computation of the boundary is correct for you?

Comment: Sorry, now I have to answer the phone...  'll  check it later

Comment: Of course. Thank you

Comment: @ggeolier Now my answer is complete.

Comment: I do not understand how do you get $4(u^2+v^2)-4(u^2+v^2)^2$. Did I do something wrong in the computation of the normal $(-4u,-4v,1)$?

Comment: You should take the outside normal $\phi_u \land \phi_v= (4u,4v,-1)$. Then  $\langle F(\phi(u,v)),\phi_u \land \phi_v \rangle=4(u^2+v^2)-4(u^2+v^2)^2$.

Comment: Ah! I see. I was taught that the normal pointing outside is the one with the third component positive. Why in this case the outside normal is negative? The surface is some kind of cone cut at $z=3.$

Comment: Also, even with your normal should'nt it be $\langle F(\phi(u,v)),\phi_u \land \phi_v \rangle=(u,v,4(u^2+v^2)^2)(4u,4v,-1)=4u^3+4v^3-4(u^2+v^2)^2$? Maybe I am missing something obvious

Comment: It is negative because it has to point downwards. Make a drawing!
$(u,v,4(u^2+v^2)^2)(4u,4v,-1)=u\cdot 4u+v\cdot 4v+4(u^2+v^2)^2\cdot(-1)$

Comment: oh jesus you are right i don't know where did I get that $4u^3+4v^3$ from... If I make a drawing of $B_1$ I just see a cone going up and stopping at $3/2.$ So since the normal points out then it has to point down. So every time I parametrize a cone the normal has to point downwards if I understand correctly?

Comment: @ggeolier Yes, exactly. Anyway, in general, a drawing will help you choosing the correct orientation.